# The best way to wait for a UI control?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, wait

I have a UserControl at which a message is being appeared gradually and after a few seconds it'll be faded again. This control uses a backgroundWorker. It works all right. But I should add an overload for the method which is responsible for showing the message as:

```
ShowMessage(string message, bool waitToHide) { .. }
```

Now, I need to know what the best way to make calling thread (the UI thread) wait for the above method is.

---

I tried to raise an event to notify the invoking scope that the inside backgroundWorker has completed, but since this method has been used frequently in the main application, I must break many unified scopes into some scattered ones.

```
{
    // before code snippet..
    messageDisplayer1.ShowMessage("test", true);
    // after code snippet..
}
```

will turn to:

```
{
    // before..
    messageDisplayer1.ShowMessage("test", true);
}

void messageDisplayer1_Done()
{
    // after..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to stick with .NET 3.5 or .NET 4 without the async CTP, I don't think you will be able to avoid splitting your code (unless you want to litter your code with [DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx), which is definitely not recommended).

On the other hand, the [async extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) (either the CTP for .NET 4 or the version included in .NET 4.5) allow you to do something like this:

```
{ 
    // before code snippet.. 
    await messageDisplayer1.ShowMessage("test", true); 
    // after code snippet.. 
}
```

Then the compiler *automatically* puts your "after code snippet" into a separate code block (a *continuation*), which is run as soon as ShowMessage has signaled completion. In the mean time, control is returned to the Windows message loop, leaving your program's UI responsive.